# Pivot Pandas column into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with Pandas to create a dataset for a personal ML project (beginner), and am very new to the library. I've come across a problem with the data in which I need to take multiple values from one column and split them into multiple columns. The problem is that the data is formatted as such:

```
COLUMN_A:
11 21 27 36 62 24
1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  9  10 11 12
etc...
```

Where the entire set of numbers is a string separated by a space.

What I need it to look like is this:

```
COLUMN_A   COLUMN_B   COLUMN_C   COLUMN_D   COLUMN_E   COLUMN_F
11         21         27         36         62         24
1          2          3          4          5          6
7          8          9          10         11         12
```

Is there a way to achieve this using Pandas? Would also be helpful to convert the string version of the number into an integer if possible.

Comment: `df['COLUMN_A'].str.split(expand=True)` ?

Comment: @anky WOW... that seemed to be the answer lol. Now I just need to add the other columns from the original df to the newly created one. Can't believe it's that easy. Sorry, new to Pandas and Python in general.

Comment: NP :) I have closed this since it has been asked before. However I am glad that it hekped you